How do I use indices in Python to access this kind of nested data?
Using the json package I have saved a local JSON file (it is exported from a website, so its structure is out of my control) as a variable like this:
path = '/path/to/json'


with open(path, 'r') as example_file:
     grades = json.load(example_file)
     print(grades)
     formatted_grades = json.dumps(grades, indent=4)


Now I want to use the formatted_grades variable to access individual values in it and do calculations with it (calculate exam averages etc.), however, the stuff I learned so far about indexing doesn't work the way I want to and I don't know why. The structure is a bit weird too, it's printed as follows:
[[{
     key:val,
     key:val,
     etc ... 

}],
[{
     key:val,
     key:val,
     etc ...
},{
     key:val,
     key:val,
     etc ...
}]]


I tried:
print(formatted_grades[0][0])  # etc.
print(formatted_grades[1][1])  # etc.
print(formatted_grades[key])  # etc.

No matter what indices I try, it always prints the whole thing or raises index errors.

Why are you converting the parsed json data back to a string? This does not make sense at all. You need to use grades, not formatted_grades

It would help if you show at least some of the file you're processing

@DeepSpace thanks for the answer! I did that to format the output with the indent=4, because with grades it outputs a continuous line which is very hard to read. Do you have suggestions for that?

@SIGHUP I can't really do that due to sensitive data, but I can try to make it more anonymous and share a copy.

Converting grades back to a string by calling json.dumps on it and then attempting to use that string to access the data makes no sense.
Use grades to access an individual sublist and then an dictionary by indexes:
print(grades[0][0]['key'])

outputs
val

or iterate over the entire structure:
for grade_sublist in grades:
    for grades_dict in grade_sublist:
        for key, value in grades_dict.items():
            print(key, value)

outputs:
key val
key val
key val


thank you! this works for the first dictionary, but not for the rest, any ideas?
